# How can I paste something at the end of the line in VIM?

Tags: vim, paste

How can I paste some text that I yanked at the end of the line?  Currently I'm doing it by pressing <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.  Is there any way to do this with a single keystroke?

Comment: Thank you, $p is already better than `A<esc>p` that I was currently using.

Comment: You know you're using vim too much when you think of 2 keystrokes as "too much of a hassle."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is if you create a mapping, e.g..

```
:nmap , $p
```

Then you can type <kbd>,</kbd> to paste at the end of the line.

Remember, one way or another, you'd have to tell Vim that you want the text at the *end* of the line, and not where the cursor currently is; by default, Vim has no single key-stroke for this.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more keystrokes, but will allow you to position the text or add other content before pasting:

<kbd>a</kbd>

`<position the cursor where you would like to paste the text>`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

Explanation: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> inserts the contents of a register. <kbd>"</kbd> is the unnamed register, containing the text of the last delete or yank.

I find myself doing this a lot when pasting comments. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.  I'm looking for economy in keystrokes, and you're suggesting something that costs more.